# Automatically protect rows when the date in this row is before today

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting

I need to automatically **protect the rows** according to the date which takes place in column A in each row, when the date is before today. I have a table with dates in the column A and different data in other columns related to these dates

I need the editor to be able to edit rows with the current date and all following days but not previous. And the next day the row with the past date shall become protected.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iEySLLmngzgFTJWWHhEZtUfU_GBxG-X77CvGTqu7U8Q/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will run whenever a user opens the spreadsheet. This will also add protection to dates that are less than the current date.

```
function onOpen(e) {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var dateRange = sh.getRange(3, 1, sh.getLastRow()-2, 1);
  var val = dateRange.getDisplayValues();
  var curDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+8", "M/dd/YYYY");
  var protectRow;
  //check if date is less than the current date
  for(var i = 0; i < val.length; i++){
    if(val[i][0]>=curDate){
      protectRow = i;
      break;
    }
  }
  
  var protection = sh.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
  //If protection exists, update else add new one.
  if(protection.length > 0){
    var range = sh.getRange(3, 1, protectRow, 13);
    protection[0].setRange(range);
  }else{
    sh.getRange(3, 1, protectRow, 13).protect();
  }
}
```

Example:

Here I replicated your data, format the dates and reopened the document.

[image]

*Note:

- The format of your dates in spreadsheet should match the format in the curDate variable.
- You can change the timezone by changing the 2nd parameter of formatDate() in curDate.
- Dates should be sorted.

References:

- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)

Comment: Thank you very much, @Nikko J.!! It really works! The only question is about changing the format of the date. I have tried dozens of variations, changed the format of the dates in the column A and the parameter of formatDate() at the same time (very accurately), but I can't make the script work for the date format DD.MM.YYYY. This is what I always use in my tables. DD/MM/YYY would also be ok. I need it to start with the day, not with the month. Is there something else within the script that doesn't allow me to change the date format?

Comment: Here is the sheet with the date format DD.MM.YYYY. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iEySLLmngzgFTJWWHhEZtUfU_GBxG-X77CvGTqu7U8Q/edit?usp=sharing And it protects the rows to the date 05.12.2020 (A3:W7).

Comment: I can't understand what is wrong with my question and why it was closed!! What is it unclear or not useful here?? Thanks to this option we can protect our work!! What can be more useful?? Now I am not sure that anybody can answer my comments above...